# firebug empty error using .filter()

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, firebug

Hi there i am tying to filter all the `ul li` items that contain an span with a class and a desired `.text()` value to be hidden this way:

```
/* string is something like 'somefilename.png'*/
    $('.qq-upload-file li').filter(function() {
        return $(this).find('.qq-upload-file').text() == string;
    }).fadeout();
```

But firebug logs this error on execution:

```
$(
[Parar en este error]   

$('.qq-upload-file li').filter(function() {
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure you've included `jQuery` in your page?

Comment: @WojtekT positive, version: 1,71

Comment: Can you post bigger fragment of your code? Maybe something before this part is wrong.

Comment: I don't speak spanish but that looks like `Syntax error`

Comment: Sorry I noticed that he clearly said, "empty error"; that text is "Stop on this error"

Comment: I reproduced a similar script and now i get a (non empty) error: http://jsfiddle.net/EumMr/1/ but still doesn't work hope it helps

Comment: try fadeOut() instead of fadeout()  (case sensitive) see http://jsfiddle.net/EumMr/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `.fadeout()` with `.fadeOut()` - case is important.

Comment: Nice, how stupid...; this stops the error, now i need to get it working, thanks!